# Facebook - Wordpress App Error Facebook returned an error: The site URL in your Facebook application settings does not match your wordpress blog URL

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog and am trying to integrate the facebook page publish version 2 app and keep getting 2 errors, one of WP:

> Facebook returned an error: The site URL in your Facebook application settings does not match your wordpress blog URL

And on FB app creator when putting in the app domain:

> This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: mywpsite.com

I have not used any http:// just the domain name.

I updated to v2 of facebook plugin, deleted the old version 1, made sure my domain name didn't have upper case, deleted the app in FB and started again and still I get this error.

When I put in the app id into wp plugin the grant access rights button stays grayed out as well, imagine that's because the app is still not set up correctly.

Any help on why I keep getting these errors would be very useful.

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: Add "Website" platform and set "Website URL" to your WP URl/domain

Comment: @Adam Azad Thanks that worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

Click the '+Add Platform' box below and depending on the app you want to add, in this case I assume click 'Website', and then add the website's URL to Site URL. This will now allow you to save the URL properly.